# How to make algebraic equations simplifier in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm actually starting to learn c++ and I'll be very grateful if someone could help me doing my first steps.
I have to make algebraic equations simplifier in c++. For example this equation:
x+5+6+3y+3+2y
should appear like this one:
x+5y+14
There is no dividing, but the program should work with +, -, and *.
I know it's easy for most of you, but I get stuck and I'll be glad if someone could tell me how should I get started with that :/

Thank you in advance,
Ans :)

Comment: Show us what you have done so far...

Comment: Show us what you have tried before asking. Also, if this doesn’t have to be in c++, python has a library called sympy which does this very well (as well as lots of other symbolic maths).

Comment: This is actually a really complex task.

Comment: @Asher Mancinelli  know how to make the last part of it, but I don't know how to start. I tried to use "for" and "while" loops, but it didn't work. So, honestly, I can say that I have nothing done :/ Unfortunately it has to be done in c++, I prefer Python too.

Comment: These are polynomials, not algebraic equations. Much easier to simplify.

Comment: In fact, in most cases you really don't need to worry about that stuff. The optimizer simplifies these at compile-time just fine.

Answer (score 7):

First, define exactly what sort of math you need to work with. These are polynomials, not algebraic equations. Much easier to simplify.

Next, pick a data structure to represent polynomials. A polynomial is a sum of terms each with a coefficient and a set of variables with exponents. In this case, all the coefficients and exponents will be integers. And, let's assume that these integers will fall within plus or minus a billion.

Already we can define some classes.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

typedef std::int32_t value;

struct power {
    char variable;
    value degree;
};

struct monomial {
    value coefficient;
    std::vector< power > product;
};

struct polynomial {
    std::vector< monomial > sum;
};
```

Next, define input and output on the classes for the given text format.

```
#include <iostream>

std::istream & operator >> ( std::istream & is, power & obj ) {
    // Skip leading space.
    std::istream::sentry s( is );

    // Read one character for the variable name.
    // Require that it be a letter.
    if ( is && std::isalpha( is.peek() ) ) {
        is >> obj.variable;
    } else {
        // Otherwise, the input is invalid.
        is.clear( std::ios::failbit );
    }

    // Read the exponent if its presence is indicated by a ^.
    if ( is ) {
        if ( is.peek() == '^' ) {
            is.ignore();
            is >> obj.degree;
        } else {
            obj.degree = 1;
            is.clear();
        }
    }
    return is;
}

std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream & os, power const & obj ) {
    os << obj.variable;
    if ( obj.degree != 1 ) {
        os << '^' << obj.degree;
    }
    return os;
}

std::istream & operator >> ( std::istream & is, monomial & obj ) {
    obj.coefficient = 1;
    obj.product.clear();

    // Read a sequence of numbers and exponentiated variables,
    // optionally separated by * .
    bool did_read_asterisk = false;

    do {
        // Try reading a coefficient. (And ignore leading space.)
        value coefficient;
        if ( is >> coefficient ) {
            obj.coefficient *= coefficient;
        } else if ( is.rdstate() & std::ios::failbit ) {
            // If it was absent, tell iostream to resume input.
            is.clear( is.rdstate() & ~ std::ios::failbit );

            // Read a power instead.
            power p;
            if ( is >> p ) {
                obj.product.push_back( p );
            }

            // It's OK if the power was missing too, unless there was a * .
            if ( ! did_read_asterisk && ( is.rdstate() & std::ios::failbit ) ) {
                is.clear( is.rdstate() & ~ std::ios::failbit );
                return is;
            }
        }
        did_read_asterisk = false;

        // Skip trailing space.
        if ( is >> std::ws ) {
            if ( is.eof() ) {
                // Succeed if this is the end of input.
                return is;
            }
            if ( is.peek() == '*' ) {
                is.ignore();
                did_read_asterisk = true;
            }
            if ( is.peek() == '+' || is.peek() == '-' ) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } while ( is );

    return is;
}

std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream & os, monomial const & obj ) {
    if ( obj.coefficient != 1 || obj.product.empty() ) {
        os << obj.coefficient;
    }
    for ( power const & p : obj.product ) {
        os << p;
    }
    return os;
}

std::istream & operator >> ( std::istream & is, polynomial & obj ) {
    // Skip leading space and reject EOF.
    std::istream::sentry s( is );

    // If there is no minus sign, start positive.
    bool positive = true;
    if ( is && is.peek() == '-' ) {
        is.ignore();
        positive = false;
    }

    // Read a sequence of monomials separated by + or - signs.
    monomial m;
    while ( is >> m ) {
        if ( ! positive ) m.coefficient = - m.coefficient;
        obj.sum.push_back( m );

        is >> std::ws;
        char next_op = is.peek();
        if ( is && ( next_op == '+' || next_op == '-' ) ) {
            is.ignore();
            positive = next_op == '+';

        } else if ( ! is.bad() ) {
            // Succeed if the next operator is missing.
            is.clear();
            return is;
        }
    }
    return is;
}

std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream & os, polynomial const & obj ) {
    bool skip_leading_plus = true;

    for ( monomial const & m : obj.sum ) {
        if ( m.coefficient > 0 && ! skip_leading_plus ) {
            os << '+';
        }
        os << m;
        skip_leading_plus = false;
    }
    return os;
}
```

Next, write the simplification logic.

```
#include <algorithm>

struct variable_order {
    bool operator() ( power lhs, power rhs ) {
        return lhs.variable < rhs.variable;
    }
};
struct variable_same {
    bool operator() ( power lhs, power rhs ) {
        return lhs.variable == rhs.variable;
    }
};

monomial simplify( monomial in ) {
    std::sort( in.product.begin(), in.product.end(), variable_order{} );
    for ( auto it = in.product.begin();
        ( it = std::adjacent_find( it, in.product.end(), variable_same{} ) )
             != in.product.end(); ) {
        value degree = it->degree;
        it = in.product.erase( it );
        it->degree += degree;
    }
    in.product.erase( std::remove_if( in.product.begin(), in.product.end(),
        []( power p ) { return p.degree == 0; } ), in.product.end() );
    return in;
}

struct power_order {
    bool operator() ( power lhs, power rhs ) {
        return lhs.variable < rhs.variable? true
             : lhs.variable > rhs.variable? false
             : lhs.degree < rhs.degree;
    }
};
struct power_same {
    bool operator() ( power lhs, power rhs ) {
        return lhs.variable == rhs.variable
            && lhs.degree == rhs.degree;
    }
};

struct product_order {
    bool operator() ( monomial lhs, monomial rhs ) {
        return std::lexicographical_compare( lhs.product.begin(), lhs.product.end(),
                                             rhs.product.begin(), rhs.product.end(),
                                             power_order{} );
    }
};
struct product_same {
    bool operator() ( monomial lhs, monomial rhs ) {
        return std::equal( lhs.product.begin(), lhs.product.end(),
                           rhs.product.begin(), rhs.product.end(),
                           power_same{} );
    }
};

polynomial simplify( polynomial in ) {
    for ( auto & m : in.sum ) {
        m = simplify( m );
    }
    std::sort( in.sum.begin(), in.sum.end(), product_order{} );
    for ( auto it = in.sum.begin();
        ( it = std::adjacent_find( it, in.sum.end(), product_same{} ) )
             != in.sum.end(); ) {
        value coefficient = it->coefficient;
        it = in.sum.erase( it );
        it->coefficient += coefficient;
    }
    in.sum.erase( std::remove_if( in.sum.begin(), in.sum.end(),
        []( monomial m ) { return m.coefficient == 0; } ), in.sum.end() );

    // Represent zero rather than "nothing."
    if ( in.sum.empty() ) in = polynomial{{ monomial{ 0, {} } }};

    return in;
}
```

Finally, tie it all together.

```
int main() {
    polynomial p;
    std::cin >> p;
    std::cout << simplify( p ) << '\n';
}
```

See, C++ ain't so bad!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a quite difficult problem. Assuming you take the data in as a string, you need to split the string on the operators to get individual components like `2x` or `14y`. You then need to check what variables are present in the expression using some sort of regular expression and convert the values to vectors in whatever vector space you’ll be in. For example, if you decide the maximum number of variables you’ll work with is 2, the vector space will be in R3. For example, `5x` will become `[0,5,0]` where the first element represents the number of numbers with no variable suffix, second element if the number of x’s, and the third is the number of y’s. In the end you should have a large number of vectors and you can sum them up to one vector and convert this back to a string to output to the screen. Python libraries like sympy require you to enter the variables you’ll be using so that it internally knows what vector space it will be computing in.

Let’s take your question as an example. It would take in the string `x+5+6+3y+3+2y` and split on the plus signs and strip the extra spaces, giving the separate strings `x`, `5`, `6`, etc. You would then convert the strings to vectors, in this case they would be `[0,1,0]`, `[5,0,0]`, `[6,0,0]`, `[0,0,3]`... where the first element represents the number of numbers with no variable suffix, second element if the number of x’s, etc. you would then sum up all the vectors to get a final vector of `[14,1,5]`, and you’ll then convert this back to a string, `’14+1x+5y’`, and print this out to the screen.

This is a concept in linear algebra called isomorphism where you can convert a set of vectors to another vector space so the problem is computationally easier (or possible). In your case you’d be transforming a set of vectors in P2 (second degree polynomial) to R3 (third degree vector in the set of real numbers), simplifying the expression, and converting the R3 vector back into P2 to give back to the user. As I’m sure you’re figuring out, this problem might be a little bit more then you were ready for with a heavy reliance on mathematics, but this could be a good exercise for you. Anyways.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The example input has no spaces. Anyway, the numeric extractor in C++ iostreams doesn't require trailing space. Without a regular expression library for sophisticated splitting, it would probably be simpler (and more conventional for C++) to construct a simple grammar and parser.

Comment: Meant to say he should split on the operators, edited. I️ tried to be as thorough as possible, this is how symbolic computation libraries work so that’s how I️ described the process.